# How to create a md file under windows

Tags: windows, git, github, git-extensions

I am using git bash under windows because I am having some troubles with Linux right now. I have to make  a commit but I have no clue how to create a file with extension `.md` under the windows platform.
could you please tell me?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `.md` (short for MarkDown) is just a text file with some fancy formatting options, like making text between two sets of `**` **bold** (GitHub, e.g., has a [pretty comprehensive guide](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)).

You can use any text editor, even Notepad, to create such a file.

Answer (score 9):

You doing the Coursera data science course as well? :)

Syntax is:

```
touch filename.md
```

Good page I have bookmarked:

http://www.typecastexception.com/post/2012/09/08/Basic-Git-Command-Line-Reference-for-Windows-Users.aspx

Comment: Any way to do via a GUI by adding it to the context window? Basically so you can right click, New -> Markdown file.